# Windows phone 7 silverlight string array in Isolated storage

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an array of strings which I am trying to store in Isolated storage, However I need to store each string in the array in  a new file of its own.
Any approach is welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: I can't help but wonder... WHY does each string need to be in its own file? Why can't they be all stored in one file?

Comment: @slugster If they add up to make quite a large file, then you will get better UX by bringing back the first one, displaying it, then loading the rest in the background.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar in an app with code roughly along these lines. Though I am serializing objects in an array to json. Same rough idea though.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    string fileName = "file" + i.ToString() + ".dat";
    using (var stream = file.CreateFile(filename)) {
      using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
        writer.Write(array[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note this is just typed straight in, I may have a mistake in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vauge, but here I go.

What is stopping you from just serializing each string to a file with the index as the name?  For example, store stringarray[0] in a file 0.xml.

Just check whether the file exists before trying to read it.